# Transform.rotate and Clip widget show nothing

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

### Steps to Reproduce

1. Create a Widget tree with the following Transfrom.rotate -> Clip -> Widget
2. if the angle is 0, everything is fine
   [image]

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Transform.rotate(
        angle: 0,
        child: ClipRect(
          clipper: Reveal(),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Reveal extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(0, size.height, size.width, -size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

3. However if the angle is non zero you get nothing
   [image]

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      body: Transform.rotate(
        angle: pi /12,
        child: ClipRect(
          clipper: Reveal(),
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Reveal extends CustomClipper<Rect> {
  @override
  Rect getClip(Size size) {
    return Rect.fromLTWH(0, size.height, size.width, -size.height);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Rect> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

### Logs

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.950], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (4 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\lovel\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 3.4)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 38.2.1
    • Dart plugin version 183.6270
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01)

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 9 (API 28) (emulator)

• No issues found!
```

Thank you

I need to reveal something while it is rotating for an animation so if there are other widgets suitable for this, please let me know